# How to use GPT-3 for fill-mask tasks?

Tags: python, nlp, gpt-3

I use the following code to get the most likely replacements for a masked word:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git
import torch
import pandas as pd
from transformers import AutoModelForMaskedLM, AutoTokenizer, pipeline

unmasker = pipeline('fill-mask', model='bert-base-uncased', top_k=100)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

results = unmasker(f"The sun is [MASK].")
for i in results:
  print(i["token_str"], i["score"]*100)
```

For example, the most likely replacement for "[MASK]" in the sequence "The sun is [MASK]." is "rising" (33.61%), "shining" (9.33%), and "up" (7.38%).

**My question: is there a way to achieve the same with GPT-3?** There is a "complete" and "insert" preset in the OpenAI playground, however, it gives me full sentences (instead of single words) and no probabilities. Can someone help?

Comment: Can you share the link to the GPT-3 model which you're using from HF

Comment: @FoundABetterName: I'm using OpenAI.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question I played around in OpenAI playground so can't be of much help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't think you can access properties like token or scores in GPT-3, all you have is the generated text.

Second of all, in my experience GPT-3 is ALL about the correct prompt. You just have to give it instructions like you were talking to a human being.

In you specific case, I would use a prompt like this:

Prompt:

> The sun is [MASK].
>
> Replace [MASK] with the most probable 5 words to replace, and give me
> their probabilities.

Result:

> The sun is shining.
>
> 1. shining - 0.47
> 2. bright - 0.18
> 3. sunny - 0.13
> 4. hot - 0.10
> 5. beautiful - 0.09

If you want to do that programmatically, here's the code:

```
import openai
openai.organization = "your org key, if you have one"
openai.api_key = "you api key"
openai.Engine.list()

my_prompt = '''The sun is [MASK].
    
    Replace [MASK] with the most probable 5 words to replace, and give me their probabilities.'''

# Here set parameters as you like
response = openai.Completion.create(
  engine="text-davinci-002",
  prompt=my_prompt,
  temperature=0,
  max_tokens=500,
  # top_p=1,
  # frequency_penalty=0.0,
  # presence_penalty=0.0,
  # stop=["\n"]
)

print(response['choices'][0]['text'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that detailed response! I assumed that there is no direct access to tokens/scores but I wanted to make sure if I miss anything. Your solution gives the exact output that I wanted, thanks!